# React page poor performance: Highlighting a region of table cells on mouse hover

Tags: reactjs

I'll first describe the problem I want to solve, and then my naive solution.

Problem: I want to have some grid of squares with a fixed size. When the user hovers over a cell, it should highlight the surrounding cells.

My solution: Use an HTML `table`, with `td`s representing cells. The table passes in a hover listener to every cell (e.g. `() => cellEnter(5, 7)` for cell at (5, 7)). The cell then calls this handler when it's hovered over, which goes to the table component which calculates which cells should be highlighted, and then updates its state to reflect which children are highlighted.

Issue: The performance on my device deteriorates once the table dimensions reach 100. I added a `shouldComponentUpdate` to the cells to only update when their highlighted state changes. Using the React chrome tool, I can see that only the relevant cells are being updated, but the table itself is also updating. The RAM and CPU usage blows up really fast.

Am I right in assuming there is no avoiding this, since the children can't re-render without the parent re-rendering. My original pure JS solution worked in `O(1)` since it just updated the cells directly. Is there a way to represent this relationship in React while keeping `O(1)` performance? Maybe the issue lies elsewhere, so I whipped up a fragment of my app (forgive the rushed code).

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLJdLo)

I'm very new to React, I appreciate any help.

Comment: My first comment is that I see, on leave/enter functions, you are completely replacing the old cells state with a new cells state, correct?

Comment: If you just want to change the color of cells on hover, then why not use CSS?

Comment: Going one step further, why not use a canvas with sprites?

Comment: @ChrisCousins Wouldn't using CSS be easier than working with a lot of JS?

Comment: Since the OP refers to performance, on client side I'd suggest canvas/sprites to be honest. All depends on the purpose of changing what is coded already; is it for learning, for performance etc?

Comment: @ChrisCousins It's partly an excuse to learn React, and partly because I like the benefits of using HTML/CSS due to things like ease of customization (just replace a CSS file to get a completely different theme), as well as accessibility (tabbing through, native tooltips, etc). If this is just a bad use case then that's completely valid, I was just wondering if I was missing something obvious.